# Combine arrays with inputs. Key->value binding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a div with input fields.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="ru">
        <input type="text" name="my_vals_ru[]">
        <input type="text" name="my_keys_ru[]">
    </div>
    <div class="en">
        <input type="text" name="my_vals_en[]">
        <input type="text" name="my_keys_en[]">
    </div>
    <div class="de">
        <input type="text" name="my_vals_ge[]">
        <input type="text" name="my_keys_ge[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I have a MySQL table, where I store some custom user data in 3 languages (English, German, Russian).

- id
- product_id
- key_en
- val_en
- key_ge
- val_ge
- key_ru
- val_ru

With javascript, I can create a lot of such constructions with inputs and send it to process by POST method.

**Now the question:** how can I find out, where the right key->value pair? If it's only one .tabs construction, there's no problem. But what if there are 5 or more?
Are there some methods in PHP or Laravel to manage it?

Comment: Are you using a library for the tabs? Or how are you making those work?

Comment: What key are you talking about? Id? Product id? // If you want to use the above HTML construct multiple times, to modify different database records - then you need to send those ids to the client first of all.

Comment: Can you add the posted data you see in your console?

Comment: I simply use jquery and bootstrap, just them.

Comment: Ok, I sent the ids to user. When I would send it back how could I determine which id belongs to input?